# How to insert additional field after third field if number of field separators in line is 5 using sed or awk

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Is it possible to run a sed command that will check the number of field separators in a line and insert an additional separator if the number of separators in the line is 5, for example?

Source data example:

```
a,aaa|bbbb|cccc|dddd|eeee|ffff|gggg
aaaa|bb,bb|dddd|eeee|fff,f|gggg
aaa,a|bbbb|cccc|dddd|eeee|ffff|gggg
```

Target output example:

```
a,aaa|bbbb|cccc|dddd|eeee|ffff|gggg
aaaa|bb,bb||dddd|eeee|fff,f|gggg
aaa,a|bbbb|cccc|dddd|eeee|ffff|gggg
```

Note: The target is to insert an additional field separator (|) immediately before or after the second field separator of the line to create a blank 3rd field, if only 5 field separators exist in the line.

If this is not possible using sed, would awk be able to accomplish the task?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/|/&/6;t;s/|/&&/2' file
```

If the number of field separators (in this case 6) is sufficient, bail out.
Otherwise, double the field separator on the required field (in this case 2).

If you only want to add the separator if there are exactly five, use:

```
sed 's/|/&/6;t;s/|/&/5;T;s/|/&&/2' file
```

Comment: ++; just to add an explanation to the 2nd command: `s/|/&/6;t` is an (effective) no-op that skips the remaining commands, if a 6th separator exists (if 6 or more separators are found on the line); `s/|/&/5;T` is a no-op that skips the remaining command, if _no_ 5th separator is found. `s/|/&&/3` is therefore then only executed for lines with _exactly_ 5 separators, and performs the requested doubling of the 2nd separator.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' 'NF<7{$2=$2 FS} 1'
```

`-F '|'` sets the input field separator to `|`.
`-v OFS='|'` sets the output field separator to `|`.

When the number of fields NF is lower than 7, a field separator FS is appended to the second field.

Comment: I believe OP needs `awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' 'NF==6{$2=$2 FS} 1' file`

Comment: @anubhava: perhaps or not, the OP has disappeared.

Comment: When you have 2 variables that MUST have the same value, for clarity and maintenance its best to set them together rather than individually to that same value: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NF<7{$2=$2 FS} 1'`. I do wish when they'd invented awk that `-F` and `FS` meant both input and output separator, while `IFS` was input (like in shell) and `OFS` was output so there'd only be one thing to set for the common case like this when you want them both the same but that ship sailed 40 years ago....

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte, anubhava and Ed Morton: Sorry for the delay is responding. Thanks for the input. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is most certainly possible with sed:

```
sed '/^[^|]*\(|[^|]*\)\{5\}$/s/|/||/2'
```

The `5` is the number of separators that will trigger replacement, and the `2` at the end of the line is the separator count where replacement will take place.

This is already a bit more readable and a *lot* more maintainable than my original attempt:

```
sed 's/^\([^|]*|[^|]*\)\(\(|[^|]*\)\{4\}\)$/\1|\2/'
```

Still, the awk solution is the best in terms of readability.

Comment: Hi Ruud, thanks for the feedback. That works for that particular instance. I also need to apply the logic to other scearios. Could you explain how the command breaks down?

Comment: sed '/^[^|]*\(|[^|]*\)\{5\}$/s/|/||/2'

Comment: I've beeen able to adapt that to work for other scenarios. The second version I have not been able to adapt. Can you explain how that one works?

Comment: The 2nd command uses a regex that consists of two parenthesized parts; the first part matches `aa|bb`, the second matches `|dd|ee|ff|gg`. The replacement part stitches them back together with an extra separator.